# Very positively skewed distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Could anyone give me an example of a sequence of cumulative distribution functions $F_i$
such that $F_i(\mu_i)\to 0$ as $i\to \infty$, where $\mu_i$ is the expected value of $F_i$?

It would be better if the support of $F_i$ is $\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

I would like to use this result for my research on OR. Thanks!

Comment: A quick-and-dirty approach, violating your $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ assumption, would be $X_i=-i$ with probability $1/i$ and $\frac{1}{1-1/i}$ with probability $1-1/i$, for $i=2,3,\dots$.

Comment: Should the means all be the same? (This question is of no consequence without the $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ assumption, because you can just subtract off each mean to make all the means the same. But with the $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ assumption, this makes a difference.)

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer! There is no problem to take different means, even if it diverges. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it carefully, there is a simpler way to do it: pick two positive numbers $x,y$ with $x<y$, give $x$ probability $p_i$ and $y$ probability $1-p_i$ with $p_i \to 0^+$. Then you get your result for free.

Comment: @Ian this post just got bumped because it doesn’t have any upvoted answers. You should convert these comments into answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p_i$ such that $p_i \in (0,1)$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_i=0$ and $x_1<x_2$. Then

$$F_i(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x \in (-\infty,x_1) \\
p_i & x \in [x_1,x_2) \\
1 & x \in [x_2,\infty) \end{cases}$$

has the desired property, since $\mu_i=p_i x_1 + (1-p_i) x_2$, which is in $[x_1,x_2)$, hence $F_i(\mu_i)=p_i$.